# Using multiple .nanorc files

Tags: nano

I am not sure if this can be done or not.  I have two different `.nanorc` files (`.nanorc1` and `.nanorc2`).  Each file has different  settings.  For example one has tabs set to 9 spaces and the other has tabs set to 4 spaces.  Each `.nanorc` file is used for different files that require different settings.

Is there a cli option that will let me choose what `.nanorc` file I want to load? Something like

```
nano -l ~/.nanorc/.nanorc1   filetoedit
```

I have read the man pages and I could not find one.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `man nano` does not show a way to specify anything other than `~/.nanorc`, you'll have to keep master copies of each variant,  and `cp` it to `~/.nanorc` before each edit.

For example, if you have `$HOME/nanorc/nanorcA` and`$HOME/nanorc/nanorcB` , and in `$HOME/.bashrc`:

```
alias nanoA="cp $HOME/nanorc/nanorcA $HOME/.nanorc;nano"
alias nanoB="cp $HOME/nanorc/nanorcB $HOME/.nanorc;nano"
```

then, "`nanoA`" will run `nano` with `nanorcA`, "`nanoB`" will run `nano` with `nanorcB`, and "`nano`" will use whichever was used last.